# ee:cpnews_feed is not writeable

Tags: error, ee3, update

I have just updated to version 3.5.1 and get the following error in the control panel.

ee:cpnews_feed is not writeable. Make sure you've set the correct relative or absolute path, and that the location is server-writable.

ee/legacy/libraries/simplepie/SimplePie.php, line 1463

Do you know how I can clear this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change permissions to system/user/cache/rss_parser/cpnews_feed to 777